# What does the Function.apply-Method do in a custom interface, when it's not overwritten?

Tags: java, interface, functional-programming, functional-interface

I have trouble understanding the use of the "apply" method in the following example code. What is the apply method doing exactly, since it's not overwritten?
It's obviously returning the result `ValidationResult`, but there is no code to back it.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Customer customer = new Customer("Alice", "alice@gmail.com", "0879546451", LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1));
                
        ValidationResult result = CustomerRegistrationValidator
        .isEmailValid()
        .and(CustomerRegistrationValidator.isPhoneNumber())
        .and(CustomerRegistrationValidator.isAdult())
        .apply(customer);
        
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

public interface CustomerRegistrationValidator extends Function<Customer, ValidationResult> {
    
    static CustomerRegistrationValidator isEmailValid() {
        return customer -> customer.getEmail().contains("@") ? ValidationResult.SUCCESS : ValidationResult.EMAIL_NOT_VALID;
    }
    
    static CustomerRegistrationValidator isPhoneNumber() {
        return customer -> customer.getPhoneNumber().contains("+08") ? ValidationResult.SUCCESS : ValidationResult.PHONE_NUMER_NOT_VALID;
    }
    
    static CustomerRegistrationValidator isAdult() {
        return customer -> Period.between(customer.getDob(), LocalDate.now()).getYears() > 16 ? ValidationResult.SUCCESS : ValidationResult.IS_NOT_AN_ADULT;
    }
    
    default CustomerRegistrationValidator and (CustomerRegistrationValidator other) {
        return customer -> {
            ValidationResult result = this.apply(customer);
            return result.equals(ValidationResult.SUCCESS) ? other.apply(customer) : result;
        };
    }
    
    enum ValidationResult {
        SUCCESS, PHONE_NUMER_NOT_VALID, EMAIL_NOT_VALID, IS_NOT_AN_ADULT;
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is the syntax to express that you want to apply these 3 functions (isEmailValid, isPhoneNumber, isAdult) to the variable `customer`. It shows how to chain multiple function invocations in one statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the apply method doing exactly, since it's not overwritten?

Depends on what static method from the interface you choose. In case of `isEmailValid`, the body of the `apply` method is

```
customer.getEmail().contains("@") ? ValidationResult.SUCCESS : ValidationResult.EMAIL_NOT_VALID;
```

> It's obviously returning the result ValidationResult, but there is no code to back it.

It's there, a `CustomerRegistrationValidator` instance is defined by a lambda.

Imagine you had to rewrite this

```
static CustomerRegistrationValidator isEmailValid() {
  return new CustomerRegistrationValidator() {
    @Override
    public ValidationResult apply(Customer customer) {
      return customer.getEmail().contains("@") ? ValidationResult.SUCCESS : ValidationResult.EMAIL_NOT_VALID;
    }
  };
}
```

to the lambda syntax. You would end up with what you have now.